# Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target in iOS 10?

Tags: objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, ios10, presentviewcontroller

I am implementing MFMailComposeViewController in my application when I click on my mail button I am get the below error.

**Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target  strong text**

Here's my code:

```
    NSString *iOSVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    NSString * version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

    NSString * build = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

    mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    mailComposer.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [mailComposer.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]}];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailComposer setSubject:@"Co - Contact Us"];

    [mailComposer setToRecipients:@[@"contact@co.org"]];
    NSString *supportText = @"Enter your comment here:\n\n\n\n\n";
    supportText = [supportText stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iOS Version: %@\nCorner Version:%@\nBuild:%@\n\n",iOSVersion,version, build]];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:supportText isHTML:NO];

    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What's wrong with my code. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If device has not configured mail or using simulator can lead to crash or exception.

```
mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

above line of code can cause problem. in simulator initializer method may return `NULL` or `nil`.

so, just check for `canSendMail` before presenting modal viewController:

Like,

```
    NSString *iOSVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    NSString * version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

    NSString * build = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

    mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] && mailComposer) {

       mailComposer.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
       [mailComposer.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]}];
       mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

       [mailComposer setSubject:@"Corner - Contact Us"];

       [mailComposer setToRecipients:@[@"contact@corner.org"]];
       NSString *supportText = @"Enter your comment here:\n\n\n\n\n";
       supportText = [supportText stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iOS Version: %@\nCorner Version:%@\nBuild:%@\n\n",iOSVersion,version, build]];
       [mailComposer setMessageBody:supportText isHTML:NO];

      [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: @visible interface for MFMailcomposerViewController declares the the selector  'canSendMail ' i am getting this error

Comment: Yes, in simulator it will not enter IF condition, check in real device@User558

Comment: yes i am checking in real device only. getting alert like this,              file:///Users/unxusmac1/Desktop/Screen%20Shot%202016-09-21%20at%202.14.47%20PM.png

Comment: No mail Accounts please set up a mail account in order to send mail

Comment: to send mail its needs to be mail account configured in device, try after configuring mail in mail app of iphone@User558

Comment: Great...HTH@User558